# Why doesn't .extend() work when using it as part of the returned expression?

Tags: python, list

I'm doing an exercise that asks to move all the zeroes to the end of a list, tried several solutions for practice, all worked, but the one I thought was the most pythonic one using `.extend()` doesn't work and returns `None`.

This works:

```
my_list = [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7, 8, 9, 0]

def move_zeros(my_list):
    l = [x for x in my_list if x != 0]
    z = [y for y in my_list if y == 0]
    l.extend(z)
    return l

print(move_zeros(my_list))
```

This also works:

```
def move_zeros(my_list):
    l = [x for x in my_list if x != 0]
    l.extend([y for y in my_list if y == 0])
    return l

print(move_zeros(my_list))
```

But this doesn't work, returns `None`:

```
def move_zeros(my_list):
    l = [x for x in my_list if x != 0].extend([y for y in my_list if y == 0])
    return l

print(move_zeros(my_list))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment causes it to return `None`. The return value of `extend()` is `None`, so `l = None` when `l = any_list.extend(any_other_list)`.

The documentation makes this clear:

```
help(list.extend())


Help on method_descriptor:

extend(...)
    L.extend(iterable) -> None -- extend list by appending elements from the iterable
```